# Executing GAMS in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, gams-math

I have created a GAMS model that takes parameters from Excel and gives back the results to another Excel file. Now, i want to run my GAMS model from the Excel VBA so that it will become more user-friendly. Is it possible to do.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you go here (https://www.gams.com/31/datalib_ml/libhtml/index.html#datalib) and filter for "vba" you will find a few examples doing exactly this.

Comment: Thanks for answer it was very helpful but since I'm beginner at VBA, these examples look so complex for me. If there is a simpler way of just running the Gams in VBA, that would be amazing.